# Как реализовать показ фотографий в виде галереи в Android из FireBase Srorage?

Tags: java, android, изображения, gallery

В моем приложении при загрузке первой фотографии пользователем в FireBase Storage создаётся личная папка(с именем как у пользователя). [image: папки]

В каждой папке хранятся все его фотографии
[image: фотки]

Нужно реализовать показ всех фоток в личной папке в виде галереи(или что-то на подобии этого). Подскажите как это реализовать?
Пробовал что-то на подобии этого https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/code-an-image-gallery-android-app-with-glide--cms-28207 , но не вышло, тонны ошибок(загружать сюда - не вижу смысла)...

Comment: Сложно помочь при такой постановке вопроса. Вы, кажется, ищите какое-то готовое решение. Готового решения такой комплексной задачи - нет. Если же вы что-то такое нашли и оно не работает - надо таки его показывать и указывать что у вас там за ошибки. Однако правильным способом решения задачи будет её декомпозирование до уровня совсем примитивных действий. Например так: 1. Получить список ссылок на все фотки. 2. Отобразить через, например, RecyclerView эти ссылки, используя Glide библиотеку, например. Приведённые задачи также можно делить на ещё более мелкие и простые.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, нет возможности протестировать работу. Но суть такая: разметка - `Grid View`. Создается адаптер, в котором получаем все изображения из нужной папки и создаем для них `ImageView`, которые являются элементами нашего `Grid View`.

В разметке прописываем:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
```

В ВашаАктивитиСГалереей.java :

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class ВашаАктивитиСГалереей extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GridView gridview = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(gridviewOnItemClickListener);
    }

    private GridView.OnItemClickListener gridviewOnItemClickListener = new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                                long id) {
            // номер позиции, можно, например, по нажатию, открывать новое активити с этой картинкой на весь экран
            String num = String.valueOf(position);
        }
    };
}
```

И адаптер:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.ListResult;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private StorageReference storageRef;
    public ArrayList<byte[]> mThumbIds;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageRef = storage.getReference();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // создание отдельного ImageView для каждого элемента
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        storageRef.child("images").child("название папки пользователя").listAll()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {

                        for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) { //проходим по всем элементам в папке
                            item.getBytes(2*1024*1024).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                                    mThumbIds.add(bytes); // добавляем в массив картинки
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    //ошибка
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // ошибка
                    }
                });

        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mThumbIds.get(position), 0, mThumbIds.get(position).length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Попробуйте так. Надеюсь, идея ясна. Возможно, где-то нужно доработать, Вы увидите, когда запустите.
Полезная ссылка:
https://abhiandroid.com/ui/gridview